# Server throwing error 405: Method not allowed while trying to communicate with my callback URL

Tags: php, laravel, url, callback

I set up a callback URL on my server, which will receive data through POST. So I set my callback route as `Route::post('/api/something', 'TheController@someMethod');` in Laravel. Now the problem is that the server can't communicate with the callback. When I check the console, I get an error that 405 standing for Method not allowed and the data object is empty. What might I be doing wrong? Check the image below for more information about the error.

[image]
NETWORK TAB:
[image]

Comment: Assuming your code is correct, are you sure you're sending a post request?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `Route::post('/api/something');`, This is what you want to do `Route::post('/api/something', 'SomethingController@method');`

Comment: I forgot specifying that but I did so

Comment: Then we need to see your controller and the Network tab of your browser where the request failed for a more descriptive error message.

Comment: I dont need the entire network requests, just the bit where that exact call was made, click on it to display the exact response error. Click on one of the 403s to show more info